# I get garbled message from RS232 to bluetooth

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, char, buffer

Equipment message :"'14/08/06"

```
bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
char c = 0;
for(int i=0;i<buffer.length;i++)
{
   int value = buffer[i];   
   Log.e(tag,"WORD="+value);                    
   c= (char)value; 


}
```

---

finally some word will be garbled (become negative),some word can show that follow ASCII

```
WORD=34
WORD=39
**WORD=-79
WORD=-76
WORD=-81**
WORD=48
......etc
```

---

become => 'ﾱﾴﾯ0ﾸﾯ0ﾷ"ﾬ"ﾱ6...

Comment: Thanks! Good luck with your app!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is not garbled, it is signed bytes.

A `byte` in java is a signed byte; `Byte.MAX_VALUE` = 127, `Byte.MIN_VALUE` = -128.

```
WORD=-79 + 128 = 49 in ASCII 1
WORD=-76 + 128 = 52 in ASCII 4
WORD=-81 + 128 = 47 in ASCII /
```